# How to check the value of customers's custom attribute in layout xml

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layout

I had added `is_seller` custom attribute to the Customer entity to mark the customer as seller. And now I want to add links to customer account left column only for the sellers. Now the problem is that how can I check the logged in customer is seller or a regular customer?

I want to check the condition in layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a custom layout handle.

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-layout-update-handles/

In the Observer method get the current customer session and do a simple IF they are a seller add your custom handle.

You can than add xml updates specific to your customers with a seller account.

Comment: I have created the handle called customer_is_seller using the observer but when i use it in layout xml no links added to sidebar
`<customer_is_seller>
        ......
</customer_is_seller>`

Comment: does the handle show if you var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());